# Millisecond sleep in C on iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Im trying to sleep for a specified amount of millisecond in C on iphone but I keep getting some complaints on the console:

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
>   nanosleep$UNIX2003 called from function ...
>
> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
>   usleep$UNIX2003 called from function ...
>
> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
>   select$UNIX2003 called from function ...

If usleep, nanosleep  and select a not available how can I sleep for ? milliseconds in C on iOS4???

Im running out of ideas here...

Tks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Use usleep(10000) (1/100th second) if you *must*, however keep it for background threads / unit tests / judicious use...

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't sleep on the main thread. for a secondary thread, use a timer, notification, operation, or pthread interfaces.

Comment: Humm... what I do is I am creating a pthread, and a Im trying to sleep while the thread is not started by evaluating a variable that I pass to the thread (which make perfect sense), if I can't do that what are my other option? Creating a pthread condition sounds a little bit useless... no?